# Использование виртуальной памяти процессом

Tags: linux, память, виртуальная-память, top

Команда `top` при выводе отображает колонку `Virt` - потребление виртуальной памяти, однако я не совсем понимаю что за виртуальная память и почему ее количество превышает реальный объем потребляемой оперативной памяти? Тобишь у меня есть приложение (микросервис) который при работе потребляет:

- 2.4G оперативной памяти
- 5.4G GPU памяти (`cuda`)
- 14.1G виртуальной памяти

На хосте при этом:

- 6G оперативной памяти
- 8G GPU памяти
- 21G памяти на диске
- SWAP отсутствует

Собственно: что означает эта цифра в 14.1G? Почему она больше всего объема оперативы (особенно учитывая что `swap` отсутствует)?

Comment: https://rtfm.co.ua/unix-raznica-mezhdu-virt-res-shr-i-swap-pamyatyu-d-rezultatx-top-i-ps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что такое в принципе «Виртуальная память» и зачем она нужна сносно описано в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C), а ещё лучше у Таненбаума в «Архитектуре компьютера» (условно-бесплатную версию легко найти в гугле). Так что строгие определения я позволю себе пропустить, и попытаюсь объяснить это «на пальцах».

При каждом запросе к памяти процессор с помощью специальных таблиц¹ (системно-зависимых и управляемых ОС) преобразует *виртуальный адрес* (*ВА*) в *физический*. Такие таблицы у каждого процесса свои и размер *виртуального адресного пространства* (*АП*) зачастую намного больше, чем реально есть памяти на компьютере, так что не для всех ВА в любой момент времени есть соответствующий адрес в ОЗУ. Более того к АП процесса могут быть подключены совершенно разные сущности:

- Собственно страницы, отображённые в физическую память.
- Запрошенные, но не использованные страницы памяти.
- Страницы памяти, сброшенные в область подкачки.
- Статические данные и код программ и библиотек.
- Обычные файлы, отображённые в память (см. [`mmap`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=mmap&category=2&russian=0)).
- Память устройств (для nix-систем это по факту отображённые в память файлы устройств).

Так вот, когда процессор обнаруживает, что произошёл доступ по адресу, которого в данный момент нет в ОЗУ происходит *страничное прерывание* (*page fault*) после чего управление передаётся от процесса к ядру ОС. Ядро ОС при этом определяет, к чему относится запрошенный адрес:

- Если это пустая, ранее неиспользованная страница, то ядро выделяет новую.
- Если страница лежит в swap'е, то ядро загружает её с диска в память.
- Если это отображённый в память файл, то ядро читает файл в дисковый кэш.
- Если это часть отображённой памяти файла-устройства, то это отдаётся на откуп его драйверу.
- Если память не принадлежит ни одному из известных отображений, то процессу посылается сигнал `SIGSEGV`.

После того как соответствующая страница подгружена в ОЗУ, управление возвращается из обработчика страничного прерывания и процессор попытается выполнить ту же самую инструкцию на котором он споткнулся перед этим.

> почему ее количество превышает реальный объем потребляемой оперативной памяти?

Это собственно заложено by-design, но всё же можно отметить ключевые особенности:

- При запросе памяти процессом физическая память не выделяется, пока к конкретной страницы памяти не произойдёт доступ. т.е. процесс может сделать

  ```
  char *foo = malloc(1<<30);
  ```

  при этом `VSZ` увеличится на гигабайт, но `RSS` не изменится, пока её не заполнить:

  ```
  memset(foo, 0, 1<<30);
  ```
- Виртуальная память помимо «памяти программы» включает ещё и различные отображённые в память файлы.
- Для некоторых библиотек и программ вполне нормально, что они выполняют одно из этих действий, так что большие значения в колонке `VSZ` `ps`'а или в `Virt` `htop`'а — это нормально.

---

<sup>¹ Определённости ради, в linux, как и в большинстве современных ОС на большинстве архитектур используется *страничная адресация памяти*. Далее речь пойдёт только про неё.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Самое первое: выделение виртуальной памяти в больших объемах - это совершенно нормальное поведение, и зависит от того, как приложение написано, и как использует эту память.

Выделение виртуальной памяти в Linux регулируется политикой, которая называется `vm.overcommit_memory` (посмотреть текущее значение можно командой `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory`), и может быть активен один из 3х сценариев работы:

`0` - Регулируемая эвристикой ядра политика выделения виртуальной памяти, при которой виртуальной памяти может быть выделено больше чем объем ОЗУ+swap (но не произвольное количество). Обычно эта политика стоит по умолчанию.
Но имеет один недостаток: при нехватке физической памяти, процесс, который думает что обращается к своему, легитимному, адресному пространству, может быть убит с признаком OOM_KILLED.

`1` - Политика, при которой ядро не следит за количеством запрашиваемого адресного пространства процессом, и разрешает выделить столько, сколько процесс запросил.
Бывает полезно для различных java программ, которые могут выделять себе по нескольку терабайт виртуальной памяти.
Недостаток, связанный с OOM_KILLED и тут имеет место быть.

`2` - Политика, при которой размер виртуальной памяти может быть контролируемым.
Регулируется в данном случае объем, настройкой ядра `vm.overcommit_ratio` по формуле:

> CommitLimit = (total_RAM - total_huge_TLB) *
>   overcommit_ratio / 100 + total_swap

Т.е. к примеру, в вашем случае, при установке `vm.overcommit_ratio = 50`
при условии что вы не используете huge pages, максимальный объем выделенной виртуальной памяти может быть: `6Gb * 50 / 100 + 0 = 3Gb`

P.S. Текущее количество huge_pages можно посмотреть `grep HugePages_Total /proc/meminfo`